# What is wrong with the regular expression [^_]?

Tags: regex

I have a file with the lines:

```
apple
,apple
crab_apple
,crab_apple
```

I would like to use regular expressions to pull out the lines 'apple' and ',apple' by using the regular expression:

```
'[^_]apple'
```

However, this outputs only the line:

```
,apple
```

What am I missing about this regular expression that prevents it from returning 'apple'?

Comment: wont it be `.?apple` instead (or `,?apple`)

Comment: @fotanus as long as it's not `_` before `apple`, it seems.

Comment: It doesn't return `apple` because `apple` doesn't have a character before it that matches `[^_]` where as `,apple` does.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing about this regular expression that prevents it from returning 'apple'?

You are missing a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<![_])apple
```

Unlike `[^_]` which *consumes* the character in front of `"apple"` after checking that it's not an underscore, `(?<![_])` simply *checks* that the character in front of `"apple"` is not an underscore, without consuming it.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/g8JubG)

Comment: Not all regex flavors support lookbehind.

Comment: @Nit That's OK - many regex flavors do, and that is clearly the concept that OP wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex

```
'[^_]apple'
```

matches strings that don't contain the symbol `_` before the word `apple`.

What you're probably looking for is more along the lines of the following:

```
 ^,?apple
```

Comment: Add `$` as well in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just apple by itself, try getting the [apple on a word boundary](http://regexr.com/38tkn).

```
\bapple\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you WANT exactely one character before `apple`, and only `apple` doesn't have any character before (that is, it has zero).

One way to get it would be:

> `'[^_]?apple'`

Meaning "zero or one-as-long-as-it's-not-_".

Comment: This will still match the line `crab_apple` since the negated character class is optional.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

> `'([^_]|\b)apple'`

it is looking for either the beginning of a word or not an underscore